# Best way to determine char codes in a function that's passed a 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I'm relatively new to google scripts. I'm passing a 2D array to a function and I want to use the charCodeAt on an array element to determine if individual chars in that element are alpha or numeric. I eventually had to move the element to a separate variable, test it there, then move it back. Is there a better way??

Thanks,

This line wouldn't work.

**if(gbGrade[gradeColumn].charCodeAt(1) >= 48 && gbGrade[gradeColumn].charCodeAt(1) <= 57 && gbGrade[gradeColumn].charCodeAt(2) >= 48 && gbGrade[gradeColumn].charCodeAt(2) <= 57)**

I had to extract gbGrade[gradeColumn] -> grade. Then it worked.

```
  function convertGrade(gbGrade){
      var icGrade; // temp variable
      var grade;
      grade = gbGrade[gradeColumn];


      if (grade.length === 3){
      if(grade.charCodeAt(1) >= 48 && 
         grade.charCodeAt(1) <= 57 && 
         grade.charCodeAt(2) >= 48 && 
         grade.charCodeAt(2) <= 57)
      {
      icGrade = grade[1] + "." + grade[2];
      } else
      {
      icGrade=grade;
      }
     } else
     {
     icGrade = grade;
     }
      gbGrade[gradeColumn] = icGrade;
     return gbGrade;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a 2D array? Judging from your code, `grade` seems to be a string, so `gbGrade` seems to be a single array. Anyway, what is your question? How to check each character in each string in a 2D array?

Comment: I believe I am. I'm grabbing all the data fro a spreadsheet, then filtering out the blank rows and putting it into a new array.var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw");
  var mydata = removeBlankGrades(sheet);
  Logger.log(mydata.length);
  var newArray = mydata.map(convertGrade);

Comment: I said that because [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) is a method of [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). You are trying to apply it to an array. This shouldn't work: it should give an error. Could you please provide more details on what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I'm just wondering is there is a more efficient way to check the two chars of that array element instead of moving them to a string and using charCodeAt, testing them in place.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense that you are not getting any error there. If `gbGrade` is a 2D array, then `grade` is a simple array and `grade.charCodeAt` should give an error. Could you please provide the code related to `removeBlankGrades` and `gradeColumn`?